# No such file or directory in pycharm

Tags: python, directory

I have a code from work that I finally got to work except for a little addition that is meant to automatically save the generated vectors on my computer, naming them accordingly.

The line of code that is having an error is

```
plt.savefig("lines/"+featureVector[15]+"_"+str(didx)+".png")
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lines/BlueConvex_0.png'
```

I thought I just need a folder called "lines" and then it would save there.

Comment: How did you run the program? Can you try changing the line to save the file in the current directory without creating the folder `plt.savefig(featureVector[15]+"_"+str(didx)+".png")` If it works then we need to look if the directory path is correct.

Comment: The error is most likely because the directory `"lines/"` doesn't exist.

Comment: The **current directory** does not have a subdirectory named `lines`.  The current directory is **not** necessarily the same as the one that contains the python script.  You can use this code to see the current directory `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: So the advice by arshovon and John did work, but for some reason I just get empty pngs now. Gotta check what thats about.

Answer (score 0):

If the current program and the current image are in the same directory you do not need to specify directory just the image "BlueConvex_0.png". However if this is not the case depending on where your writing your program (I suggest vscode) you can find the full file path by right clicking.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).